# lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment

Tags: spring-boot, lombok

I updated java version to 8 to 17.

Springboot project when clean and install then this error show.

lomboc is not work

I want to install and build springboot maven project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using lombok with JDK 17, no issue.
Try updating the lombok version in pom file:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.24</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```